# Tornado SSL certs

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, openssl, tornado

I have a question about tornado SSL configuration. I wanna handle HTTPS protocol. I also read docs and stackoverflow same issues. I have a SSL certificate & key files. Code looks like

```
settings = dict(
    ...
    ssl_options = {
        "certfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.crt"),
        "keyfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.key"),
    },
    ...
)
def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.web.Application(handlers,
                  **settings))

    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

After I starting my app. I wanna access from browser https://mydomain.com but it is not working and nothing happened it gives unsuccess request error. What should I do? BTW http://mydomain.com:443 is working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are passing the settings to *tornado.web.Application()* instead of *tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer*

Try this,

```
settings = dict(
    ...
    ssl_options = {
        "certfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.crt"),
        "keyfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.key"),
    },
    ...
)
def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.web.Application(handlers), 
                  ssl_options = {
    "certfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.crt"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.key"),
})

    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Update:

```
settings = dict(
    ...
    ssl_options = {
        "certfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.crt"),
        "keyfile": os.path.join("certs/myserver.key"),
    },
    ...
)
def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.web.Application(handlers), **settings)

    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Praveen thank you for your answer but how about other settings?

Comment: in settings dict there is key arguments for example template_path. Now  tornado gives TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_path' error

Comment: Praveen thank you. I did it. You gave me clear direction

Comment: The simplest way to create keys is to run " openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout certs/myserver.crt.key -out certs/myserver.crt.pem " based on http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html   Thank you Praveen for your answer.

Comment: @AhmadYoosofan url 404s. Here's an archive link for those still interested: https://web.archive.org/web/20220303053549/jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html